# Django syncdb - NameError: name '*********' is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django & Python and have been following a tutorial, but I have an error that has me stumped.

I am attempting to build my django models / database.

When I attempt to run *python manage.py syncdb* I receive the following error in my command line prompt:

```
C:\Users\6233114\Django-Projects\GlobalX>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 231,
 in execute
    self.validate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 158, in
 get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 64, in
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 88, in
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\6233114\Django-Projects\GlobalX\app_data\models.py", line 15, i
n <module>
    class LanguageCode(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\6233114\Django-Projects\GlobalX\app_data\models.py", line 27, i
n LanguageCode
    languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(languageDirection, default=1, db_col
umn="languageDirectionID")
NameError: name 'languageDirection' is not defined

C:\Users\6233114\Django-Projects\GlobalX>
```

This is a cut down version of my models.py file (lines 1 - 29):

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class LanguageDirection(models.Model):
      languageDirectionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="languageDirectionID")
      languageDirectionDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="languageDirectionDescription")
      languageDirDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="languageDirDescription")
      textAlign = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="textAlign")
      oppositeLanguageDirectionDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="oppositeLanguageDirectionDescription")
      oppositeLanguageDirDescription = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="oppositeLanguageDirDescription")
      oppositeTextAlign = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_column="oppositeTextAlign")
      class Meta:
        db_table="languageDirection"

    class LanguageCode(models.Model):
      languagecodeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="languageCodeID")
      languageCodeDescription = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="languageCodeDescription")
      baseLanguageCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="baseLanguageCode")
      languageNameEng = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="languageNameEng")
      altLanguageNameEng = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="altLanguageNameEng")
      languageNameNative = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column="languageNameNative")
      altLanguageNameNative = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="altLanguageNameNative")
      iso639_1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, db_column="iso639_1")
      iso639_2T = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="iso639_2T")
      iso639_2B = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="iso639_2B")
      iso639_X = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="iso639_X")
      languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(languageDirection, default=1, db_column="languageDirectionID")
      class Meta:
        db_table="languageCode"
```

The relationship between LanguageDirection & LangaugeCode is a one-to-many, where LanguageDirection.LanguageDirectionID (one) and LanguageCode.LanguageDirectionID (many).

Any suggestions as to what is causing this error and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(languageDirection, default=1, db_column="languageDirectionID")` should be `languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageDirection, default=1, db_column="languageDirectionID")`.  The error refers to the issue that languageDirection, which should refer to the *class name* and not the DB table name for the foreign key target, is not capitalized correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I should have know better. What a stupid mistake by me.

Answer (score 4):

This is the meat of the error:

```
languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(languageDirection, default=1, db_col
umn="languageDirectionID")
NameError: name 'languageDirection' is not defined
```

The line should be:

```
languageDirectionID = models.ForeignKey(LanguageDirection, default=1, db_column="languageDirectionID")
```

Since the ForeignKey takes a class, or the name of a class in quotes such as `"LanguageDirection"`.

NameError, for the future, means you're attempting to use a variable that is either not in scope, or does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Something that happened to me a few times is that when defining the models in Django, the Foreign key field relates to a model that´s defined further down in the same document.

This gives me no warnings in Pycharm 2.7 which I consider somewhat odd. Anyways, to solve this just put '' around the class name.

`models.ForeignKey('SomeModel')`